# How to set global variable value from class level variable in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, variables, public

In my vb.net application that is have multiple project working together. I'm using `flag` as a global variable that can be accessible throughout the application but having problem. I have another flag named variable in another module and I want to assign flag value with another flag.

**Project 1**

```
Module Abc
    Public flag as String = "Hello"
End Module
```

and another flag variable is in another project.

**Project 2**

```
Module Pqr
   Public flag1 as String = flag
End Module
```

But it is giving error that

> Abc is not declared or inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: As far as I know this is only possible in three scenarios: **1)** Via interprocess communication **2)** By saving the value as a file on the harddrive, or **3)** By using [**Memory Mapped files**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) (similar to option 2).

Comment: [**Working with memory mapped files in .NET 4**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/salvapatuel/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4/).

Comment: but if i use file for saving value and again the value of flag is changed it will take previous values.

Comment: Not with Memory Mapped files you won't. And if you use normal files you can use a [**`FileSystemWatcher`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to monitor for changes. -- You see I wouldn't have recommend it if it wouldn't fully do what you need :). -- If you choose to use your own files you have to implement a system to notify for changes.

Comment: But your very best option is actually to use Memory Mapped files (shared memory), as scenarios like this is exactly what they're designed for (I should've been more specific in my first comment and stated that this is your best choice).

Comment: Caveman just made me realize that I might have interpreted your question incorrectly. How do your projects "work together"? Is one project an executable file and the rest DLLs referenced by the exe? Or are some of your other projects also exes? **And finally:** Is it _**only**_ your exe that references the other projects, or does for example one DLL reference another DLL?

Comment: Because what I thought you wanted was to share memory between different processes or multi-referenced DLLs, so I might have misinterprered your question completely.

Comment: It is one project an executable file and the rest DLLs referenced by the exe.

Comment: Ok so the DLLs do not reference each other? Then you don't need Memory Mapped files :>. But it's hard to see the actual problem, try the answers and if they don't work, please share some more code.

Comment: project 1 has project 2 reference and if i assign the value of flag1 to flag it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error it's correct, try this:

```
PUBLIC Module Abc
    Public flag as String = "Hello"
End Module
```

Comment: How is this even related? He wants to access a variable from a different project/different executable (which is possible in numerous ways), this is only setting a local variable and will not be related to the other project(s).

Comment: @VisualVincent I'm supposing asker only needs to access a variable from a different project, which is referenced. I think you're going further

Comment: That's not how I interpreted the question, but perhaps you're right. Up until now every time I've read or re-read it it has always felt the same to me. Though he never explicitly states either, it's easy to find out.

Comment: Though if multiple projects are referencing each other I don't think their similar references share memory. For example if **EXE A** references **DLL B** and **C**, and **DLL B** also references **DLL C** then the exe and **DLL B** won't share the same memory with **DLL C**. -- So it all comes down to getting to know his actual situation.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes, more info is needed

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reference the first project in the second one:
right click on it and add reference, from the solution tab select the first project, make your module public as Caveman mentioned, then in your code import the first project namespace as the following:

First Project:

```
Namespace Test
   Public Module Abc
      Public flag as String = "Hello"
   End Module
End Namespace
```

Second Project:

```
Imports WindowsApplication1.Test
   Public Module Pqr
      Public flag1 as String = flag
   End Module
```